# documentation for ulogd columns

Tags: mysql, iptables

I have ulogd2 set up to log packet info to mysql.  However, I cannot find any documentation anywhere telling me what the various fields are.  A lot of them I can intuit what they are, but some, I have no real idea.  Can anyone advise me on what the "oob" prefix is?

Here's an excerpt of the columns with this prefix:

```
`oob_time_sec` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
`oob_time_usec` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
`oob_hook` tinyint(3) unsigned default NULL,
`oob_prefix` varchar(32) default NULL,
`oob_mark` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
`oob_in` varchar(32) default NULL,
`oob_out` varchar(32) default NULL,
`oob_family` tinyint(3) unsigned default NULL,
`oob_protocol` smallint(5) default NULL,
```

Almost all the rest of the fields, I have a good idea what the prefixes mean and what's in the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stands for "out of band" and is storing metadata regarding the packets (data which is not stored within the packets themselves).  For example, the time the packet was recieved should be in the `oob_time_sec` and `oob_time_usec` fields, though this information was not derived from the packet itself.